# Whilst creating a SQL function, how do i check whether a table is used in the current query that the function is called into?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express, sql-function

My main query is:

```
SELECT 
a,
b,
c,
my_function(d),

into
    temp  
from
    trade t,
    party pt,
    portfolio pr
```

What I want my function to do is check if a particular table is used in the join (for eg, the table 'portfolio'). If so, than it will execute a certain block of code and return some value. If  the table does not exist, it will proceed to next block of code within the function and return some value.

**What i want to know is how do i accomplish the part of checking if a particular table is used in the current query/join and 'code' this check into the function?** I am not looking to check if the table is present in the database, but only if it is present in the current query that the function is being called in.

Function will be something like:

```
`

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION maturity_date   
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @d  int>
)
RETURNS date >
AS
BEGIN

    -- I want to do the check here.I wnat to check if a particular table exists, 
    -- if so then execute the  1st block, else execute 2nd block

   --1st block
    Begin

    RETURN end_day

    End

    Else 

    --2nd block
    Begin

    RETURN expiry_day

    End



END
GO
`
```

Comment: Still question is unclear, can u add some sample data please, also script used in the function aswel

Comment: This is actually impossible to do accurately. There are way too many possibilities for this to be correct. Slight detour....https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: thanks i added a skeleton of my function's code (not detialed), hopefully that is enough to narow the scope of my query?

Comment: With your latest edit it sounds like you are only wanting to check for the existence of a table? That is pretty simple. Look at OBJECT_ID. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql I would also point out that scalar functions are notoriously horrible from a performance standpoint. Often they can be converted to an inline table valued function which is a lot better for performance and more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

The function has no inherent access to the query that called it.

The only way the function could know if a table was present in the calling query is if you passed it as a parameter.

EDIT:   After reading the edit to your question, my answer above is still accurate, but I would further propose that I think you would be better off writing two functions.  SQL Functions should be simple and do only one thing.  Writing a single function that does one thing in one case, and something different in another case is over-consolidating.